# On definite integrals $\int_0^n \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{k-1}}{\zeta(k)} dx$, where $\zeta(y)$ is the Riemann zeta function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory

The following article from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Harmonic_numbers_for_real_and_complex_values) show us these formulas for harmonic numbers $H_x$: the Taylor series for $|x|<1$, and formulas for $\int_0^m H_x dx$ for integers $m\geq 1$.

Now one defines for real numbers $0<x<1$ 
$$M_x:=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n-1}}{\zeta(n)}.\tag{1}$$
(I don't know if previous real numbers $M_x$ are well-known.)

> **Question.** A) Can you calculate or provide me hints to calculate a good approximation of 
>   $$\int_0^1 M_x dx?$$
>
> B) Do you know if was in the literature a closed-form, for each fixed integer $m>1$, of $$\int_0^m M_x dx$$ in terms of special functions,  or well asymptotics of such definite integral as $m\to\infty$? If yes, then aren't required more details, please refer the literature. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I appreciate, if in next future someone knows in the literature the integrals in B) refers it as a comment. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M_x = \sum_{n\geq 2}(-1)^n x^{n-1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m^n} = x\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m(m+x)}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m+x}\tag{1}$$
hence
$$\int_{0}^{1}M_x\,dx = -\sum_{m\geq 1}\mu(m)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)=\color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n\,\zeta(n)}}\approx 0.15294. \tag{2}$$
The integral over a different interval can be managed in a similar way, leading to a slow-convergent series that can be easily accelerated, for instance by approximating $\frac{1}{\zeta(n)}$ with $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ for large values of $n$.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and answer.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, I am unable to understand the second and third  equality in equation (1), could you please add a hint?

Comment: @Anaedonist: the first equality comes from the algebra of Dirichlet series, $\zeta(s)^{-1}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m^s}$, the second identity comes from partial fraction decomposition and $\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}=0$, that is a consequence of the PNT.

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{n} (\frac{1}{\zeta(n)}-1)$ doesn't converge slowly

Comment: @user1952009: I guess that depends on what we call *slow* or *fast*, the general term of such series behaves like $\frac{1}{n 2^n}$, but a general term decaying like $\frac{1}{4^n}$, $\frac{1}{n!}$ or $\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$ would have been much better for numerical purposes.

Comment: In that case $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(k) (\ln(1+k^{-n})-k^{-n})$